# Fiz um código para enviar na tela o numero do cpf, está funcionando mas acusando um erro!

Tags: php, array, mysqli

```
<?php   
        include"conectar.php";

$query="select cpf from teste where cpf = '" . $cpf . "' order by teste";
$stmt=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($stmt) {

     $today = date("d.m.y");
} else {
     mysqli_rollback($con);
     echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
}


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt) )
{   
                  $cpf = $row['cpf'];

}


mysqli_close($con);          
        ?>
```

o erro é  seguinte....

```
Transaction rolled back.

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Lembrando o resultado está ok! Mas acusa este erro! Obrigado!

Comment: Leste a mensagem de alerta?

Comment: Não entendi Jefferson, pode ser um pouco mais claro?

Comment: Sim, posso: você viu o que tem depois de "warning: " até o final da linha?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in......while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt) )
{ 
              $nome = $row['nome'];
          
}

Comment: E esse alerta significa o quê?

Comment: Dica: você parece estar ordenando pelo nome da tabela ao invés de ordenar pelo nome da coluna.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson resolvido o problema!

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque o problema foi resolvido sem respostas.